# How to remove empty lines from a text file? Java

Tags: java

I have a text file in which I want to read in, remove all non-alphabetic characters and white space including the empty lines. Then convert the text to lowercase. This is what I have so far in terms of the code:

```
public static String replace(String file ){
    String plaintext = "";

    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(file));
        while(input.hasNext()){
             //text = text + input.nextLine();
             plaintext = input.nextLine();
             plaintext = plaintext.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
             plaintext = plaintext.toLowerCase();
             System.out.println(plaintext);
        }
        input.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found. ");
    }
    return "";
}//end of replace method
```

The only problem I'm facing is that I am not sure how to removed the black lines of spaces in between each paragraph of the text file. My output shows like this:

> csthesciencethatdealswiththetheoryandmethodsofprocessinginformationindigitalcomputersthedesignofcomputerhardwareandsoftwareandthe
>   applicationsofcomputers
>
> itthedevelopmentimplementationandmaintenanceof
>   computerhardwareandsoftwaresystemstoorganizeandcommunicateinformation
>   electronicallyabbreviationit
>
> computersaremanmadetoolsthataidusinsolvingotherproblemsabiologististryingtofigureouthowlifeworksphysicistsandchemistsaretryingtofigureouthowitemsreactinouruniversemathematiciansaretryingtofigureoutrulesformanmadesystems
>
> anyresearchproblemthatmayimproveacomputerscapabilityofhelpingsolveaproblemoranyresearchproblemthatshedslightaboutanewwaytodosomethingwithacomputerispartofcs
>
> mostexcitingresearchmedicalapplicationsexpertsystemsfordiagnosis

Comment: Have you tried calling `trim()` on the strings you want to eliminate spaces?

Comment: But, anyway, are you facing any error? bad result? What is really your question?

Comment: I assume you're just testing with that method so far since it would always return an empty string. Besides that, what's the problem with checking the length of `plaintext` after you've removed everything except ascii letters?

Comment: When I run the code, it leaves the line of space in between each "paragraph" as the original text file has it. It does not remove the empty line spaces. I would like for those to also be removed but not sure how to edit my code

Comment: Your regex tells that you only really care about the pure ASCII charset; no accentuated characters at all, then?

Comment: No. I want it pretty basic. Just letters A-Z all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work; please note that it makes use of the JSR 203 API as far as file handling is concerned (since Java 7; in store for 10+ years for you to use) and of Java 8 for streams and their associated methods. Also note that it won't work with code points outside the BMP:

```
public static String trimFile(final String file)
    throws IOException
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final Path path = Paths.get(file);

    try (
        final Reader r = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
    ) {
        int c;
        while ((c = r.read()) != -1)
            if (Character.isLetter(c))
                sb.appendCodePoint(c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

A little explanation here:

- we don't need anything else than a `Reader` given the requirements; and even though `Files.newBufferedReader()` returns a `BufferedReader`, we don't care about reading line by line, therefore we downgrade it to a `Reader`, and we trust the JRE implementation to do its thing;
- the `read()` method of a `Reader` returns an int... This is fine given the requirements (ie, we should not expect code points outside the BMP);
- the `Character.isLetter()` implementation used is the one that takes an `int` as an argument, well, so what: as stated in the previous point, we don't expect code points outside the BMP, in which case this method behaves the same way as its counterpart expecting a `char`, so no harm done;
- we do, however, have to use the `appendCodePoint` of `StringBuilder`; this class' `.append` method taking an int as an argument will append the string representation of the integer as an argument, but this is not what we want.